# Macro is working but keeps getting RESOLVEDATAMACRO errors

Tags: macros, kentico

We are getting tons of MACRORESOLVER error on one of our pages and I was able to pinpoint where it is coming from. We have a macro in a static html web part like the code below and I can't figure out what's wrong. It is working as expected too so I'm confused. Is the syntax wrong? Hoping someone can help me.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 newsltr-two-btn">
  {% if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Document)) { %}
  <a target="_blank" href="~/getattachment/{% Document %}/attachment.aspx" download>{% DocumentText %}</a>
  {% } else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ExternalDocumentUrl)) { %}
  <a target="_blank" href="{% ExternalDocumentUrl %}">{% DocumentText %}</a>
  {% } #%}  
    </div>      
</div>
```

Event Log:

Error while evaluating expression: if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Document)) { print(ResolveMacros("\r\n {% DocumentText %} \r\n ")) } else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExternalDocumentUrl)) { print(ResolveMacros("\r\n {% DocumentText %} \r\n ")) } |(user)paulo|(hash)7b864efc818f93934b7bfb4c7d92234dc8c506e841ed30c3b661f8bee604d86b

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
at CMS.MacroEngine.ExpressionEvaluator.EvaluateCondition(Boolean& match, Boolean& securityPassed, DataRow drLogItem, DateTime evaluationStarted)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your syntax has an error in it.  See notation below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 newsltr-two-btn">
  {% if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Document)) { %}
  <a target="_blank" href="~/getattachment/{% Document %}/attachment.aspx" download>{% DocumentText %</a> // your error is here, missing a closing curly brace after the percent sign for DocumentText
  {% } else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ExternalDocumentUrl)) { %}
  <a target="_blank" href="{% ExternalDocumentUrl %}">{% DocumentText %}</a>
  {% } #%}  
    </div>      
</div>
```

Also, if you're using a static HTML webpart, I'd suggest moving it to a static text webpart.  Reason being the static text doesn't validate AND correct any of the HTML you input.  This could also be the issue that the WYSIWYG editor is modifying your markup and causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it was just a typo error. I corrected it.

Comment: I tried the text static web part but no luck. What I ended up doing is to use a repeater web part so I can use an ASCX transformation. Thanks Brenden!